# How to use azure devops pipeline counter in bash?

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, semantic-versioning

I want to use a `counter` to have unique build numbers in case my version string has not changed.

This is my config:

```yaml
  - task: Bash@3
    name: GetSemVer
    displayName: Get semantic version
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        SEMVER=$(./gradlew printVersion | grep 'Version: ' | awk -F' ' '{print $2}')
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=semver;isOutput=true]$SEMVER"
        BUILDINCREMENT=$[counter('semver', 0)]
        BUILDVERSION=$SEMVER$optionalBuildTag-$BUILDINCREMENT
        echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$BUILDVERSION"
```

I want to get a version like this:

```
1.0.0-beta.2+029.sha.16177d4-1
```

But I get this error:

```bash
/home/vsts/work/_temp/7388d9ae-e885-4bcb-b6a7-4226978a77d7.sh: line 3: counter('semver', 0): syntax error in expression (error token is "('semver', 0)")
Async Command Start: Update Build Number
Update build number to 1.0.0-beta.2+029.sha.16177d4- for build 6742
Async Command End: Update Build Number
```

The counter suffix is missing from the build-number.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to mix runtime expressions like `$[counter]` and variables defined during a pipeline's run.

Comment: I am using to jobs now, where I echo the SEMVER in the first and define the other variables in the variables block of the second job.